# C# HttpWebRequest 403 Forbidden on BitStamp API Post

Tags: c#

I am using BitStamp for Bitcoin trading and I am trying to use the API to check my balance.

When I test the API using Postman with either form-data or x-www-form-urlencoded without authentication both works just fine. Even just posting through the browser it works perfectly:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>
        <form action="https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/balance/btcusd/" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="key" value="SomeKey" />
            <input type="text" name="signature" value="SomeSignature" />
            <input type="text" name="nonce" value="123456789" />
            <input type="submit" value="Test" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

But doing it with HttpWebRequest I keep getting an exception 403 Forbidden error

```
try
{
    HttpWebRequest getApiRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/balance/btcusd/");

    getApiRequest.Method = "POST";

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    getApiRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;";
    string FormData = "key=SomeKey&signature=SomeSignature&nonce=123456789"
    StreamWriter formWrite = new StreamWriter(getApiRequest.GetRequestStream());
    formWrite.Write(FormData);
    formWrite.Flush();
    formWrite.Close();

    StreamReader resultReader = new StreamReader(getApiRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
    string result = resultReader.ReadToEnd();
    resultReader.Close();
    return result;
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
    return e.Message;
 }
```

I have looked at the posts in Fiddler, but for the most part it seems the same. But admittedly I am not sure that I am using Fiddler right. I have tried Content-Type "multipart/form-data;" with the FormData written correctly with borders and everything, no luck. I have tried setting a User Agent, still no luck. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that even though an exception is thrown, if it is a web exception I can still get a response.

```
catch (WebException we)
 {
    StreamReader resultReader = new StreamReader(we.Response.GetResponseStream());
    string result = resultReader.ReadToEnd();
    resultReader.Close();
    return result;
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
    return e.Message;
 }
```

From the response I saw that the nonce I used is one I had used before and hence the error.